# Convert formula to arrayformula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

How can this formula be rewritten into array formula variant?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D4),"",IF(AND(D4="Long", G4<=E4), "No trade", IF(AND(D4="Short", G4>=E4), "No trade", IF(AND(I4>=E4, H4<=E4), "Target Hit", "Active"))))
```

Comment: depends on which one you prefer... if you are happy with it then delete your question. if you want array formula from it just say so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the array formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D4:D), ,
 IF((D4:D="Long") * (G4:G<=E4:E), "No trade", 
 IF((D4:D="Short") * (G4:G>=E4:E), "No trade", 
 IF((I4:I>=E4:E) * (H4:H<=E4:E), "Target Hit", "Active")))))
```